# In Monotouch, is it possible to save a generic list to to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: .net, ios, generics, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a `List<Hashtable>` in my MonoTouch app, and I need to persist it to my settings.  `NSUserDefaults`, however, only takes in things that inherit from `NSObject`.

Is there a simple way to wrap my List in an `NSObject` that I can store in my settings, or is a quick generic way to encode and decode a `Hashtable` to a JSON string (or similar)?

Or is there a MonoTouch alternative for persisting a small list of `Hashtable`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Maxim said there are several approach available. If you want to use `NSUserDefaults` to store your data then you can serialize it (a .NET feature available to you using MonoTouch) to either:

- **a binary format**. Then use the `Stream` (or `byte[]`) to create an `NSData` instance that you'l be able to store with `NSUserDefaults`; or
- **into a string** and store it as a `NSString` (`string` overloads are also available, but it will do the `NSString` conversion);

Comment: Saving it as a byte stream because the most straight forward way for me to do what I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not save your data into SQLite-table?

You could create quiet simple table with fields:

- id - auto inc int - primary key;
- list name - string - to identify exact list;
- list data - byte[] - list's data.

For List -> byte[] (and vice versa) conversion try to use such code:

```cs
public static class Bytes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to get byte array from a object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_Object">object to get byte array</param>
    /// <returns>Byte Array</returns>
    public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray (object obj)
    {
        try {
            var _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
            var _BinaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter ();
            _BinaryFormatter.Serialize (_MemoryStream, obj);
            return _MemoryStream.ToArray ();
        } catch (Exception _Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString ());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static T ByteArrayToObject<T> (byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        var memStream = new MemoryStream ();
        var binForm = new BinaryFormatter ();

        memStream.Write (arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
        memStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var result = default(T);
        try {
            result = (T)binForm.Deserialize (memStream);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Deserialize error {0}", ex);
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```