# Hidding field in root.plist file

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, settings.bundle

I use a root.plist file for setting my monotouch iPhone application based on this article:

http://adtmag.com/articles/2010/04/13/working-with-application-settings-in-monotouch.aspx

How we can have a field that by default is invisible and the application, based on conditions, can change the visibility?

Comment: Why not store setting of your monotouch app in sqlite database? It's more flexible than plist-files. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14322497/548395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings are by default hidden.

If you do this:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardDefaults;
defaults.SetInt(21, "TestInt");
defaults.Synchronize();

Assert.That(defaults.IntForKey("TestInt"), Is.EqualTo(21));
```

It will be completely hidden if you don't setup anything in your plist file. (NOTE: I'm using NUnit here)

So if you want something hidden, don't add the value to your Settings.bundle or Root.plist.